# How can I prove that this matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant, diagonalization

How can I prove that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the following matrix is diagonalizable? I computed the characteristic polynomial, but I couldn't decompose it into linear factors. This is the polynomial: $t^2-3t+2-a^2$ What should I do next?

Here is the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & a \\
a & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Well, what do you usually do in that case?

Comment: I cry. I try to compute the eigenspace but that is not helping me much atm

Comment: You have a symmetric matrix.  Does that mean anything?

Comment: What happens for $a=\sqrt 2$?

Answer (score 0):

Find the zeors of the polynomial. If there are two of them, you are done else you have to take a closer look at the eigenspace and check if it is two-dimensional.

Comment: But how do I found the zeros of this polynomial:
t^2-3t+2-a^2=0. 

i found for a=0 that t=1 and 2.

but i need to show that for all a this is okay. And now i showed it for a=0

Comment: @esma2708, you surely know a formula to find the roots of a degree two polynomial!

Comment: Holy moly... the abc-formula haahha thaaank you

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant of the polynomial is
$$
3^2-4(2-a^2)=1+4a^2
$$
For all real values of $a$, the discriminant is positive. What does this tell you about the roots of the polynomial?

What is a sufficient criterion for diagonalizability? (In other words, you *don't* need to compute the eigenspaces, in this case.)

Comment: I found 2 values of t. So it is diagonalizable, because we have two eigenvalues?

Comment: @esma2708 Yes, two distinct real eigenvalues make a $2\times 2$ matrix diagonalizable.